# Двусмысленная функция в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Сделал класс, унаследовал его от `QWidget` и `QGraphicsItem`, для того, что-бы иметь графический элемент с сигналами и слотами. Теперь при желании воспользоваться методом QGraphicsItem::pos(); происходит ошибка, компилятор пишет что такой метод двусмысленный(ambiguous), то есть он не знает от кого из предков брать pos(). Устранил проблему поменяв класс родитель с `QWidget` на `QObject`, однако есть вопрос:

Если нет возможности менять класс родитель, каким образом избавится от двусмыслености?

Comment: Подозреваю, что перед вызовом такого метода нужно произвести приведение к нужному классу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще говоря наследование от `QWidget` и `QGraphicsItem` единовременно выглядит для меня странно, т.к. эти сущности друг другу ортогональны, да и тот факт, что Вы с лёгкостью смогли отказаться от `QWidget` в качестве родителя, говорит о  том, что он Вам не сильно-то и нужен. Поэтому я бы советовал оставить вариант без `QWidget`.

Что же касается непосредственно вопроса: Вам нужно явно в классе наследнике указать, какую функцию Вы хотите использовать, чтобы убрать двусмысленность:

```
class A
{
public:
    int pos()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    float pos()
    {
        return 0.0f;
    }
};

class C: public A, public B
{
public:
    using A::pos;
};
```

Или же как Вам посоветовал в комментарии @Etki - Вы можете приводить объект наследника к типу одного из родителей и вызывать соответствующие методы.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал такого)